# SQL Server if else statements not working correctly

Tags: sql-server

I have created user defined function in SQL Server, but somehow the logic is not correct, it always executes the else statement; please help!

```
CREATE FUNCTION shipSelection
    (@Item_No varchar(20),@itemname varchar(20))
RETURNS varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @weight float
    declare @demention float
    declare @density float
    declare @result varchar(100)

    SET @weight = (SELECT Item_Weight FROM Items 
                   WHERE Item_No = @Item_No AND Name = @itemname) 
    SET @demention = (SELECT Dimention FROM Items 
                      WHERE Item_No = @Item_No AND Name = @itemname)

    SELECT @density = @weight / @demention

    IF @density > 100
    BEGIN
        SET @result = 'LOW DENSITY CAN USE ANY TYPE SHIPS';
    END
    ELSE IF @density > 300
    BEGIN
       SET @result = 'MEDIUM DENSITY CAN USE MEDIUM SHIPS';
    END
    ELSE IF @density > 500
    BEGIN
        SET @result = 'MEDIUM DENSITY WANT TO USE HUGE SHIPS';
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
       SET @result = 'DONT WANT TO CARE ABOUT SHIPS TOO SMALL DENSITY ITEM';
    END

    RETURN @result
END

SELECT 
    dbo.shipSelection('I010', 'asus x555l') AS TRANSPORT_SHIP_TYPE
```

Comment: Can you show the record that you are looking up please

Comment: I suggest that you add some debug code to select the whole record of to show the result when you populate dimension and weight

Comment: That's, how I pass values to  function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you have the logic, it's always going to hit either the first case (> 100), or the else (< 100).  Try checking the largest numbers first.

It will never hit the > 300 case, because it will use the > 100 case first.

If you are always hitting the else statement, you'll need to check that your value is actually greater than 100.  Sounds like it isn't.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to us that it fixed your problem. It is customary to accept the correct answer ( @PhillipXT) so that he gets the credit and to help future users with a similar problem to find the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I bet that one of your queries returns a NULL value. Since null is not a number and cannot be compared with a number your else statement, in the case of null, will be hit. You can prevent this by setting the value of the query returning null to a known value using `COALESCE`.

```
    SET @weight = (SELECT COALESCE(Item_Weight,0) FROM Items 
                   WHERE Item_No = @Item_No AND Name = @itemname) 
    SET @demention = (SELECT COALESCE(Dimention,0) FROM Items 
                      WHERE Item_No = @Item_No AND Name = @itemname)
```

Comment: The demention variable should maybe default to 1, because he's doing division with it afterwards.

Comment: Personally, I prefer checking for divide by zero condition with a CASE statement rather than setting the value using COALESCE. If @demention is used after the division then you will need to keep a mental tally of it being 1 instead of zero. Just my two cents.

Comment: SELECT @a=CASE WHEN @c=0 THEN 0 ELSE @b/ @c END...however you are not wrong and I am not right:)

Comment: As long as it's checked for before the division, it's all good  :)